# How to stop busy javascript program?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to write a nodejs express server. In that, I need to set time for execution. let say I made a request to /endpoint1 in express from the postman and that endpoint will trigger a function that contains an infinite for loop. My doubt is it possible to set the time limit for a single request?

```
....
app.get('/endpoint1',(req,res)=>{
    while(true){}
});
....
```

Comment: No there's no way to set a time limit for blocking code. Use asynchronous non-blocking code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do anything about that within the same execution context of your application.

What you could try to do is to have a controlling/observing parent process that spawns your application. And that application sends regularly „heartbeat“ messages to the parent if those are missing the parent can restart the application.

In general, it is a good idea to write you express in such a way and in addition to this to use the [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster) capability of node, so if one worker becomes unresponsive for whatever reason, that you only need to restart that one worker.

Comment: is it possible to interrupt the running process and ask to clear event loop

Comment: @KarthikNedunchezhiyan no, if your process is blocked by a none interruptable endless loop you will have no other choice then doing a hard kill. There will be no option to do any cleanup from within the application that is stuck within the endless loop.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this will work,

```
//type 1
var server = app.listen();
server.setTimeout(500000);

//type 2
app.post('/xxx', function (req, res) {
   req.setTimeout(500000);
});

//type 3
app.post('/xxx', function (req, res) {
    res.setTimeout(3000, function () {
        console.log('here')
    });
});
```